# Increment property in array of objects, conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am incrementing the value on `rank` by one till the `name` property changes, I am using the `page` and `rank` properties to determine when that happens.

But I would also like to increment it once when the `type` is not equal to `none` and resume when it does again.

I almost have it with this, but I seem to be one step behind, as when the `type` returns to `none` still not incrementing.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'another' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 3, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 3, type: 'none' }, 
  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
]

let counter = 1

const results = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  if (obj.page === 1 && obj.rank === 1) 
    counter = 1

  obj.rank = obj.type === 'none' ? counter++ : counter

  acc.push(obj)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(results)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Desired output

```
[
  { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'other' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 3, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 4, page: 2, type: 'none' },

  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 3, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 3, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 3, page: 3, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 4, page: 3, type: 'none' },

  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 3, page: 2, type: 'none' },

  { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 3, page: 2, type: 'none' }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the rank should increase when either the current or the previous type is "none". You can access the previous one via the third and fourth argument to reduce.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 3, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 3, type: 'none' }, 
  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
]

let counter = 1

const results = data.reduce((acc, obj, i, data) => {

  if (obj.page === 1 && obj.rank === 1) 
    counter = 0;

  obj.rank = [obj.type, data[i-1]?.type].includes('none') || !i ? ++counter : counter;

  acc.push(obj)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(results)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot about the `optional chaining` `?.`

Comment: There is one problem with this answer, if the first object `type` is also not `none`, its rank would be 0

Comment: True, I added `|| !i` to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 3, type: 'something_else' },
  { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 3, type: 'none' }, 
  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'not_none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' },
  { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' },
]

let counter = 1
let skip = false

const results = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  if (obj.page === 1 && obj.rank === 1) {
    counter = 0
    skip = false
  }
  if (obj.type !== 'none') {
    if (!skip) {
      skip = true
      counter++
    }
  } else {
    skip = false;
    counter++
  }
  
  obj.rank = counter

  acc.push(obj)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(results)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The condition could maybe be condensed to:

```
  if (obj.type === 'none' || !skip ) {
    skip = (obj.type !== 'none')
    counter++;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually managed to do it by using the `index` and `array` other arguments in the `reduce` method to go back in the array and check its type

Comment: Right. You need some kind of history information there. "Skip" was my choice.

Comment: I did this:
  `if (obj.page === 1 && obj.rank === 1) counter = 0`
  `if (obj.type === 'none' || index === 0)  counter++`
  `else if (index > 0 && array[index -1].type !== obj.type ) counter++`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this, it addresses the fact that if the first object `type` is also not `none` it would still add rank 1, thanks to everyone for the responses and to `trincot` for remind me of the `optional chaining`

```js
const data = [ { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'other' }, { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' }, { name: 'car', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' }, { name: 'car', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' }, { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' }, { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' }, { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'somethingelse' }, { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'somethingelse' }, { name: 'bike', rank: 1, page: 3, type: 'somethingelse' }, { name: 'bike', rank: 2, page: 3, type: 'none' }, { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'not_none' }, { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'not_none' }, { name: 'moto', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' }, { name: 'moto', rank: 2, page: 2, type: 'none' }, { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 1, type: 'none' }, { name: 'bus', rank: 2, page: 1, type: 'none' }, { name: 'bus', rank: 1, page: 2, type: 'none' }, ]

let counter = 0

const relative = data.reduce((acc, obj, index, array) => {

  if (obj.page === 1 && obj.rank === 1) counter = 0
  if (obj.type === 'none' || array[index -1]?.type !== obj.type) counter++
  
  obj.rank = counter
  acc.push(obj)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(relative)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```